# Show/Hide group of polylines in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, toggle, polyline

I want to toggle visibility of group of polylines. In my file I can show/hide markers, but when I try to do the same with polylines it just show/hide the last created polyline.
In the future I would like to categorize my polylines and toggle just polylines with one colour. But for now I'd be happy if somebody can help me with toggling all polylines. I think problem is in a loop.
Here's my file:
http://www.2shared.com/document/C01NN3u5/Polylines.html

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array for each polyline category. Push each polyline object into the adequate array. To toggle them off, loop through a specific array and call setMap(null) on each polyline.

Having an array myArray containing some polylines, you could do something like

```
for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {

    myArray[i].setMap(null);
}
```

Do the same if you need to toggle them on again using `setMap(yourMapId)`

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me. Here is my function showing/hiding polylines:                                                  function displayLines(){
 
 var p;       

 for (p = 0; p < polylines.length; p++) 
  if(polylines[p].getMap(map))

    { 
     polylines[p].setMap(null); 
    }
       else 

    { 
     polylines[p].setMap(map);
    }
}

Comment: @MrUpsidown will you please answer this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455280/hide-polyline-from-a-to-b-using-in-google-map-api-v3)