# Hide polyline from A to B using in Google Map api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am displaying google map with code below, I want to hide Polyline between A to B. All answers on google talk about creating an array and then doing `array.setmap(null)`. can I hide polyline without using arrays. In other case, how should I use array to hide polyline using code below.

**Edit:** I need marker A and B to be shown

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var time;    
function initialize() {

        var rendererOptions = {
            map: map,
            draggable: true               
        }
        // Instantiate a directions service.
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

        // Create a map and center it on islamabad.
        var islamabad = new google.maps.LatLng(33.7167, 73.0667);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: islamabad
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        calcRoute();
    }

    function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('MainContent_txtFrom').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('MainContent_txtTo').value;
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }      
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You did everything right. You only need to call `directionsDisplay.setMap(null);` to remove the route.

Comment: by writing ``directionsDisplay.setMap(null);`` map didn't render at all. It keeps showing center

Comment: Well at what point do you want to remove it? And where did you add the above code?

Comment: I'm drawing map after user fills start and end locations textboxes, I want to show only A and B marker but not blue line between them. And I tried ``directionsDisplay.setMap(null);`` both before and fter ``directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);`` and also outside of the ``directionsService.route(...){...}`` block

Comment: Sorry but why would you need the Directions Service if you don't want to display a route?

Comment: Because route specifies that user will go from this route. My requirement is to show that user has to go from A to B only, and he is not bound of any path/route. Means user can go from any possible route, not specified by map

Comment: Then just display 2 markers for A and B. I still don't see why you would need the Directions Service if it's just to display 2 points on a map.

Comment: Hmmm...your suggestion is good, I should think about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to render the directions but hide the polyline, use the [DirectionsRendererOptions suppressPolylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions).

```
function initialize() {

    var rendererOptions = {
        suppressPolylines: true,
        map: map,
        draggable: true               
    }
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
```

Comment: That's great. That's what I was searching for. This is the exact and simple answer of my question but as @MrUpsidown suggested that I don't need ``Directions Service`` just to show A and B markers and not route, so that's the better idea as well (explained for future questioners).

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the demo below, you can remove polylines by two means:

- setting the option `suppressPolylines` to *true* in `directionsDisplay`, your `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` by using

  ```
  directionsDisplay.setOptions({
          suppressPolylines: true
        });
  ```

  This will preserve the start- and end-point markers.

  The method `setOptions(options:DirectionsRendererOptions)` changes the options settings of [`DirectionsRenderer`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.22/reference#DirectionsRenderer) after initialization.
- use `directionsDisplay.setMap(null);` to remove all directions rendering, but this includes markers, so if you do that you will need to add extra markers to the map.

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var time;

var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(48.86, 2.35);
var pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(33.7167, 73.0667);

function initialize() {

  var rendererOptions = {
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    }
    // Instantiate a directions service.
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

  // Create a map and center it on islamabad.
  var islamabad = new google.maps.LatLng(33.7167, 73.0667);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: islamabad
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = pointA;
  var end = pointB;
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
};

function removeRoute() {
  directionsDisplay.setOptions({
    suppressPolylines: true
  });
  // this "refreshes" the renderer
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
};

function removeRouteNull() {
  directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<button onclick="removeRoute()">Remove route (suppressPolylines)</button>
<button onclick="removeRouteNull()">Remove route (setMap(null))</button>
<button onclick="initialize()">Undo all</button>
<section id="map"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to this answer: [Google Maps v3 directionsRenderer.setMap(null) not working to clear previous directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666050/google-maps-v3-directionsrenderer-setmapnull-not-working-to-clear-previous-dir) you should see what you're looking for.

You do not need to use an array as you're implementing the directionsRenderer object. If you declare this globally (*Edit* Which I now see you have already) (so that you only have one instance at any given time) then you can simply use directionsDisplay.setMap(null) to remove previous directions rendered.

If you want to render the markers from the response but hide the polyline I suppose the simplest (but I would imagine by no means cleanest) way would be to simply alter the opacity on the polyline object:

```
var myPolylineOptions = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.00001,
    strokeWeight: 0
});
```

And then assign it to your renderer:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({polylineOptions: myPolylineOptions});
```

Comment: by writing ``directionsDisplay.setMap(null);`` map didn't render at all. It keeps showing center

Comment: By the way I don't have issue of rendering previous directions

Comment: Do you just want to hide the polyline then? But keep the start finish point etc?

Comment: I think that should accomplish what you're looking for, but may not be the cleanest solution.